# Old ExpressionEngine builds

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, meta

Is there an official resource for downloading previous EE builds for add-on development/testing.

I have recently started archiving all versions of EE and add-ons that I install, however I have only started this recently (EE 2.7.0+). It would be awesome if there was somewhere I could access older versions of EE for supporting my add-ons, as well as making sure new add-ons are backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try contacting EllisLab directly and ask them. I think they were in the process of finding some way to make older versions of the software available to licence holders.

Comment: I reached out to Ellislab with no response as of yet. Marking this answer as accepted for now.